# Upon successive runs of my python code eventually crashes my computer

Tags: python, pygame, ubuntu-12.04

It seems that when I run my code the first few times it runs beautifully but then after about the 3rd to 4th time I run it it begins to slow down. That is my computer becomes unresponsive as it seems to develop some lag. Eventually this crashes my computer and it makes coding in IDLE difficult. I'm running on ubuntu 12.04 on a laptop that has a dual core 1.8 ghz processor and 2gbs of memory. I don't think I'm pushing the hardware with this one

```
#Beating Heart Game

#imports
import pygame
import random
import math
from pygame.locals import *

#Intialize Modules
pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()

#Globals
WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 600
FRAME = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

#Colors
GRAY = (100, 100, 100)
NAVYBLUE = ( 60, 60, 100)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = ( 0, 255, 0)
BLUE = ( 0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 128, 0)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)
CYAN = ( 0, 255, 255)
BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
NEARBLACK = ( 19, 15, 48)
COMBLUE = (233, 232, 255)

#Helper Functions

#Class Cell
class Cell:

    def __init__(self, radius, color, pos):
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.pos = pos

    def get_position(self):
        return self.pos

    def move(self):
        pass

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, self.color, self.pos,self.radius, width=0)


#Class Heart
class Heart:

    def __init__(self,radius,color,pos):
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.pos = pos

#Objects
cell = Cell(5, PURPLE, [WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2])
pygame.draw.circle(FRAME,PURPLE,[WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2],10,0)


#Game loop
class loop(object):
   gameloop = True
    while gameloop:
        pygame.display.set_caption("Beating Heart")
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameloop = False
                pygame.display.quit()              
            pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

I just started this program so the code is just a framework as of now

Comment: "run my code the first few times" - as in close it, start it again, close it again, etc., or do you mean something else?

Comment: So I run my program that opens up a display and a shell. I close the display and the shell and then run the program again. I'm using like a python text editor to run the program

I noticed my CPU's oscillate between 80-100% but is the program really that intensive?

Comment: No, no script should take that much CPU in python. Can you make sure that the actual PROCESS is killed when you "close"? It's possible that you're running several instances, hence taking up a lot of CPU.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out, I just haven't been able to phrase what I'm experiencing correctly. I think when I run pygame it is running as fast as the CPU will let it and it is causing some problems. I think I need to cap the FPS that the game is running or the amount of events that it can handle per second. I'm guessing this is the culprit will update if this is the case. I just don't know the best way to do this.

Comment: YUP that was the problem. Wow that had been bothering me for some time, I guess I just needed somewhere to sit down and phrase what I was experiencing. Thanks though for reading this guys

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, not an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Turns out pygame will run as fast as the CPU will let it and so when running the program CPU usage shoots up to 100%. To limit this insert an object

```
clock = pygame.timer.Clock()
```

then in the gameloop

```
clock.tick(60)
```

where '60' is the allowed fps.

That was not clearly explained to me in how to write the gameloop.